# Firefox right-click opens lengthy non-responsive context menu

Tags: firefox, context-menu, right-click

When I tried to save a picture I noticed when I right-click in Firefox it opens up a long menu, that wasn't like this before. Here is what it looks like now:

[image: 1]

No matter what I click on, nothing happens. No page opens in a new tab, no photo is saved... Does anyone know what might have caused this and how to fix it?

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you try to save a picture that you searched for using [Google images](http://images.google.com)?

Comment: image link is broken, please update it.

Comment: I experienced this the other day when upgrading from Firefox 19 to Firefox 20. I didn't look into it much, unfortunately. I simply deleted my Firefox profile and created a new one.

Comment: Try Firefox button / Help menu / Restart with Add-ons Disabled / Safe Mode and see if the problem persists. If it doesn't, reopen Firefox normally, press Ctrl+Shift+A, then disable add-ons manually one by one till you find what's causing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw the same after updating to Firefox 20.0.1. Though Firebug addon didn't report it needed restart, relaunching Firefox after disabling Firebug fixed the context menu. I understand that in your case there may be no Firebug at all. In mine it was Firebug 1.10.2; version 1.11.2 works ok.

Comment: Ah! I believe you are correct. A Google search for [`firebug long right click menu`](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebug+long+right+click+menu) shows many other users reporting the exact same problem around the same time.

Comment: Thank you Alexander. That is exactly what it was. I disabled firebug 1.10.2 and restarted the browser and and the right click menu is now fixed!